# Remove BOM from XML files for the subdirs using dos2unix in Windows

Tags: xml, windows, dos2unix

I have some problems with BOM symbols in a large amount of XML files nested in the subdirectories. Some of them have the BOM and I need to remove it. I can do it for the exact directory like this:

```
dos2unix.exe -r d:\path\to\directory
```

But I need something like a BAT file to remove BOM for the files in the subdirectories to save the time. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you don't need a batch file, but just `for /R %X in (*.xml) do dos2unix -r %X`

Comment: How should I use it? Can you please write an exact example for the BAT file?

Comment: Like that - it's not a batch file but a command line. (Inside a batch file you'd use `%%X` )

Comment: Thank you. It was useful for me.

Comment: I can't run the bat file with this code. Only in a command line.